# How do I can pull the latest row having the latest row.date, and keeping all other values?

Tags: sql, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm currently trying to extract latest visited domain information from a table that includes a visits history on my websites and information I want to retreive.

Here is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `visit_record` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `date` VARCHAR( 19 ) NOT NULL,
    `url` VARCHAR( 1024 ) NOT NULL,
    ... EXTRA COLUMNS/DATA ...
    PRIMARY KEY ( `id` )
);
```

Here URL stands for multiple pages on same or different domains.

But I want to get all columns for the latest row for each distinct domain, and my URL store a full query, not a domain only (for more flexibility regarding other features).

The problem is, my distinct value to group on is a calculated value. I tried mixing the solution from the post shown in examples I tried, with grouping / left joins / different structure of queries / subqueries, but I cannot manage and as soon as I want to add my other values/columns (for e.g ID of the row, extra data), it show 99% of the time the following error:

`SELECT list contains nonaggregated column`

(even if I found basic queries on internet looking like my-ones).

As I want to group by domain I'm first extracting a domain name as a column, in a query I'll use later with an alias:

```
SELECT
    `visit_record`.`id`,
    `visit_record`.`date`,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( `visit_record`.`url`, '/', 3 ), '://', -1 ), '/', 1 ), '?', 1 ) AS `domain`
FROM
    `visit_record`;
```

Here everything is ok, and I see an additional column having my domain name without protocol and query details.

Now I would like to take the latest (MAX) row: the row having the latest date, and get only 1x per unique domain.

I already found part of the solution I guess, thanks to some topics such as the-ones below:
[Select info from table where row has max date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432913/select-info-from-table-where-row-has-max-date)
[SQL query to get the latest row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75618134/sql-query-to-get-the-latest-row)

But I seems tricky / requiring modifications to fit my use case.

I'm not providing more examples because I made 15+ tries and I don't know which-one is the best to start from, but I guess you have enough information to help me on this!

Data sample of visit_record table:

```
id      date                    url                                 extra columns
_________________________________________________________________________________
1       2023-06-21 00:00:00     https://example1.com/en             ...
2       2023-06-20 23:00:00     https://example1.com/uk             ...
3       2023-06-20 14:00:00     https://example2.com/en/about       ...
4       2023-06-21 03:00:00     https://example2.com/fr             ...
```

My expected output:

```
id      date                    url                                 domain          extra columns
_________________________________________________________________________________________________
1       2023-06-21 00:00:00     https://example1.com/en             example1.com    ...
4       2023-06-21 03:00:00     https://example2.com/fr             example2.com    ...
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

**Problem Reformulation**

The main problem was performing this domain extraction from URL and grouping on it, as it is not a primary key, by keeping all columns of the row which is the "latest" (by date) one of each domain.

**SOLUTION**

Get for each domain which is not a primary key (extracted from an URL value), the latest-row by date (which is not a primary key too), including all the related row columns.

This query will add a last column "domain" and return the result:

```
SELECT
    t1.*
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *,
            SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( `visit_record`.`url`, '/', 3 ), '://', -1 ), '/', 1 ), '?', 1 ) AS `domain`
        FROM 
            `visit_record`
   ) t1
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            domain,
            max( date ) lastdate
        FROM (
                SELECT
                    *,
                    SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( `visit_record`.`url`, '/', 3 ), '://', -1 ), '/', 1 ), '?', 1 ) AS `domain`
                FROM
                    `visit_record`
            ) t0
        GROUP BY domain
    ) t2 ON
        t1.domain = t2.domain
        AND t1.date = t2.lastdate;
```

Comment: What values are in date, and how do you determine which is latest?  better to use date or datetime types, not strings.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output. Also, define what does the "latest" means? Your `date` column is defined as `VARCHAR( 19 )`.

Comment: Date is a "Y-m-d H:i:s" formatted date (stored as string) @ysth, and I cannot give more details about latest, I mean latest is latest: the most recent date registered.

Comment: I added data sample and expected output, sorry for late @slaakso

Comment: General discussion of efficient "groupwise-max" techniques:  https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select * 
from(
  select *,row_number()over(partition by domain order by date desc) rn
  from (
    SELECT *,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( 
           SUBSTRING_INDEX( `visit_record`.`url`, '/', 3 )
             , '://', -1 ), '/', 1 ), '?', 1 ) AS `domain`
    FROM  `visit_record`
   )t1
  )t2
where rn=1;
```

Result

| id | date | url | EXTRA_COLUMNS | domain | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-06-21 00:00:00 | https://example1.com/en | ... | example1.com | 1 |
| 4 | 2023-06-21 03:00:00 | https://example2.com/fr | ... | example2.com | 1 |

Updated:
if `row_number()` not available in your version of MySQL, use this example:

```
select * 
from (
    SELECT *,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( `visit_record`.`url`, '/', 3 ), '://', -1 ), '/', 1 ), '?', 1 ) AS `domain`
    FROM  `visit_record`
   )t1 
inner join (
  select domain,max(date) lastdate
  from (
    SELECT *,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( `visit_record`.`url`, '/', 3 ), '://', -1 ), '/', 1 ), '?', 1 ) AS `domain`
    FROM  `visit_record`
   ) t0
  group by domain
  )t2 on t1.domain=t2.domain and t1.date=t2.lastdate
;
```

[Example here](https://dbfiddle.uk/FREHtMih)

Comment: Hey, just tested, but unfortunatelly, I get the following error:

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by domain order by date desc) rn from ( SELECT *, SUB' at line 3`

Comment: @Lucas: which version of MySQL are you running (`select version()` will tell you)? Window functions are available in MySQL 8.0 only.

Comment: Answer updated for earlier versions of MySql

Comment: Amazing @ValNik ! this is working properly on my side, I just see 2x times the "domain" column, but I guess I can manage from here

Comment: Thank you as well for letting the original / recent solution available, so I can use it in case of a migration or upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

(A long Comment on Lajos's Answer.)

```
select vr1.id, vr2.`date`, vr1.URL
from visit_record vr1
join (
    select url, max(rec.`date`) as `date`
    from visit_record rec
    GROUP BY url
) vr2  ON vr2.url = vr1.url
      AND vr2.date = vr1.date
```

This should get a row for each URL.  But if there are dup dates, it can deliver multiple rows for a given URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the actual table with an aliased table that finds the maximum date, order by id descendingly and take the first row only.

```
select vr1.id, vr2.`date`, vr1.URL
from visit_record vr1
join (
    select max(rec.`date`) as `date`
    from visit_record rec
) vr2
on 1=1
order by id desc
limit 0, 1
```

This should work properly with your format of **Y-m-d H:i:s**, although, I strongly recommend to use actual date columns rather than varchars that are logically dates.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much! This actually works, but the thing is this works for only 1x domain no? How can I get this result, but for each distinct domain of the list?

Comment: I guess I can left join a table of distinct extracted domains an get this result for all of them, but there's maybe an easier / more efficient way.

Comment: @Lucas you can group by domains. Before I edit my answer to solve this problem, can you tell me exactly what your distinct domains are? If you can tell me that, then I can help you further. Is each distinct `URL` value a separate domain?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the offer of help, unfortunately there will be multiple domain I want to add later (I did not create yet) and from 0 to multiple pages, so the better option should be to group by domain without targeting a specific one.

Comment: @Lucas there's nothing unfortunate in that. It is a resolvable problem. All that I need in order to help you with that is to know the exact definition of what you call a domain. If you could edit your question with a query that shows **exactly** how you would get the distinct domains, then the problem would be easy to solve for me.

Comment: See my answer for fixing the 1x "bug".

Comment: @RickJames thanks, that makes a lot of sense. I will not edit my answer to avoid plagiarism :) But I did upvote your answer.